# JBoss AS7 cluster: mod_proxy or mod_cluster

Tags: apache, jboss, cluster-computing, mod-proxy, jboss7.x

I'd like to establish a cluster of JBoss AS7 servers. I've found that it may be done using apache with `mod_proxy` or with `mod_cluster`. Which one would you use? Which one is easier to establish and  maintain? Which provides better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modcluster.

mod_cluster has Server-side load balance factor calculation and Fine grained web-app lifecycle control.

see "Advantages" at http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster .

Comment: Finally I used mod_proxy as it was easier to deploy. Maybe we switch to mod_cluster later.